# How to change style of cursor for all inner div through id of mother div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I would like to change the cursor style of all the elements/divs inside a div even when one or more inner divs have already a set style of the cursor:

HTML:

```
<div id="motherDiv">
  This div has a cursor set to "pointer"
  <div id="subDiv">
    This is the child div
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#motherDiv {
    background:#f0f;
    padding:20px;
}
#subDiv {
    cursor: default;
    background: gray;
}
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("motherDiv").style.cursor = 'pointer';
```

https://jsfiddle.net/NguyenVanKhoi/f793vjjs/5/

In JS code, the cursor style is "pointer" for the outer div. I also want to apply it for the inner div through this, but it does not work. The inner div's style of the cursor seems to be fixed (cursor: default) and cannot be changed.

How can I change it for all the divs included inside one parent div by using JS/AngularJS/jQuery? Thank you!

**EDITED:**
I do not want to fix it in css, i would like to change it to progress cursor and can be reverted to normal for motherDiv and sub div.
Finally, I use this in CSS:

```
.progress {
    cursor: progress;
}
.progress > * {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

then I use jquery to handle to add progress to mother div.

Comment: Override it in CSS

Comment: #motherDiv *{
    cursor: pointer !important;
}

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/f793vjjs/6/ but i would change the specificity of the selectors

Comment: I would not use `!important` it overrides to much

Answer (score 1):

simply by css:

```
#motherDiv,
#motherDiv div {
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

This way, the mother div and all his descedant divs willl have with the `cursor: pointer` attribute.

Anyway, this line of code 
`document.getElementById("motherDiv").style.cursor = 'pointer';` it's a bad habit of working with angular: you should use either [ng-style](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) or [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) for those purposes.

Comment: except he asked for a js implementation.

Comment: The Js implementation it's not raccomended: you can do all simply using a css class. if you need JS, you can use ng-class or ng-style as mentioned in my post

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with CSS:

```
#subDiv {
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 .cursor {
  cursor: pointer;
 }
```

this will be help

```
jQuery('#motherDiv').hover(function () {
  jQuery(this).find('#subDiv').addClass('cursor');
  }, function () {
  jQuery(this).find('#subDiv').removeClass('cursor');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should give the `#motherDiv` the property `cursor: pointer;` then give the `#subDiv` any property you want ... 
then ..... check my javascript code

```js
document.getElementById("motherDiv").className = 'all';
```

```css
#motherDiv {
    background:#f0f;
    padding:20px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#subDiv {
  cursor: wait;
    background: gray;
}
#subDiv1 {
  cursor: help;
    background: gray;
}

#subDiv1 {
  cursor: crosshair;
    background: blue;
}
.allDivs  ,#motherDiv div{
  cursor :pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="motherDiv">
  This div has a cursor set to "pointer"
  <div id="subDiv">
    This is the child div
  </div> <div id="subDiv1">
    This is the child div
  </div> <div id="subDiv2">
    This is the child div
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the children() method gets all tags that are inside the selector-tag.
the selector is motherdiv. subDiv is inside motherDiv, so the following will apply css to the subDiv.

```
$("#motherDiv").children().css("cursor", "pointer");
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
jQuery('#motherDiv,#motherDiv div').css('cursor','pointer');
```

```js
jQuery('#motherDiv,#motherDiv div').css('cursor','pointer');
```

```css
#motherDiv {
    background:#f0f;
    padding:20px;
}

#subDiv {
    cursor: default;
    background: gray;
}
#sub-sub-div {
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="motherDiv">
  This div has a cursor set to "pointer"
  <div id="subDiv">
    This is the child div
    <div id="sub-sub-div">
      THis is grandchild div
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, using CSS:

```
#motherDiv, #motherDiv div {
  cursor:pointer !important;
}
```

```css
#motherDiv {
    background:#f0f;
    padding:20px;
}

#subDiv {
    cursor: default;
    background: gray;
}
#sub-sub-div {
  background:green;
}
#motherDiv, #motherDiv div {
  cursor:pointer !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="motherDiv">
  This div has a cursor set to "pointer"
  <div id="subDiv">
    This is the child div
    <div id="sub-sub-div">
      THis is grandchild div
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```